# Angular RxJS: custom pipable - Observable<{}> and Observable<void>

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Argument of type 'UnaryFunction, Observable>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UnaryFunction, Observable>'.

I'm trying to solve this compilation error:

```
const defaultQuery = () => map(() => <pojo.Query>{
    filter: this.cercacodi,
    offset: 0,
    limit: SearchComponent.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE
});

// Grab search button click event
this.searchQuery$ = this.$searchClick.pipe(defaultQuery());  //<Compilation error here>
```

where:

```
private $searchClick: Observable<void>;
private searchQuery$: Observable<pojo.Query>;
```

Compilation error is:

```
Argument of type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<{}>, Observable<Query>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<void>, Observable<Query>>'.
  Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<void>'.
    Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'void'.
```

Comment: With Observable of type **void** you probably can't do anything, except return it. So you can't pipe it also because it wont emit any values and your custom lettable operator (`defaultQuery()`) also wont receive them. And an error is telling you that - it expects type of value of Observable to be `{}` but gets `void`.

Comment: What about adding some cast on `defaultQuery`. It returns `Observable<{}>` but I guess there was a posibility to add some cast on function interface.

Comment: It won't make any difference from what I see. Problem is with `$searchClick: Observable<void>`and `pipe(`. You can't pipe Observable that returns `void`. Because `void` could be value like `console.log()` or `window.write()` - you can't pass around any of these. IWhy dont you change `Observable<void>` to something like `Observable<any>`?

Comment: Yes. I've ended up changing to `Observable<any>`... I was expecting for any casting-like work-around...